# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in calculation.php on line 5

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to calculate the difference between two dates in php. I am trying with the following code, here I am getting the above error. How to solve this one?

```
<?php
      date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$date1  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');    //2012-03-10 17:58:52
$date2 = 2013-07-03  10:25:50;
$difference = (strtotime($date2) – strtotime($date1)) / (60*60*24);  
      echo "date is".$difference ;  ?>
```

I need the differece with both date and time.  Where is the problem giving error?
If I try like this, 
    $difference = abs(strtotime($date2) – strtotime($date1));
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE`
Thanks.

Comment: So you posted a piece of code without telling us what's line 308. Also, you opt to create a question on SO before giving trying to solve this (trivial) problem yourself clearly states in what bad shape today's "programmers" are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution, I have change the code for you.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$date1=strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));    //2012-03-10 17:58:52
$date2=strtotime("2013-07-03 10:25:50");
$diff=($date2-$date1)/(60*60*24);

 echo "<BR>date is".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$diff);
```

It is working for me try yourself and check it.

Comment: Hi Harry,
but the result is coming like this 2050922
I want like this  y-m-d h:m:s

Comment: Ok use this code echo "<BR>date is".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$diff);

Comment: I have updated my code plz check it.

Answer (score 1):

Your date2 variable should be in quotes as it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

For `$date2`, you haven't assigned it as string by enclosing it in Single or Double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following:

```
$date2 = 2013-07-03  10:25:50;
```

To:

```
$date2 = "2013-07-03  10:25:50";
```